# Open HTTP Basic auth only on a specific domain/request

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, domain, subdomain, http-basic-authentication

Are we, **Apache Commandos**, able to do this:

Open the HTTP Basic Authentication dialog box in a browser only if I request some URL from a specific domain name/server name/host name?

For instance:

If I'd be requesting:

```
localhost
some_custom_localhost
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.123
etc...
```

I shouldn't be poping up the HTTP Basic Authentication. But if I'd do this:

```
www.somehost.com
sub.somehost.com
213.214.15.16 *(meaning a public internet IP)*
```

I should get my HTTP Basic Auth poped out, and have my credentials stored under my ".htpasswd", etc.

Is this even posible as I've described it?

Answer (score 0):

[**As the documentation describes**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html), HTTP auth can be as granular as you need.

You can certainly decide access by (name-based) vhost, as long as the content they serve is different.

Comment: meaning I should just add a virtualhost for my specific IP/Hostname/Domainname, and it's directives I can setup the HTTP Basic Auth?

Comment: You should probably spend some time on [**basic virtual hosting with apache**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

Comment: that's not the answer to my question: should I just add a directive on the specific domain or not?

Comment: Your question makes bad assumptions; the documentation I pointed you to explains how authentication works.